# python - Find a portion of a text file to export as data to manipulate

Tags: python

I have a text file and from it I want to extract everything below a key word and nothing above another word. I particularly care about numeric values inside this portion of text. Let me show you the text I mentioned:

```
// Region of Interest file
// Data set: XXX^XXX
// File created: Mon Feb 13 10:44:31 2017

//
// Pinnacle Treatment Planning System Version 9.10 
// 9.10 
//

 file_stamp={
       write_date: Mon Feb 13 10:44:31 2017
    write_program: Pinnacle Treatment Planning System
    write_version: 9.10
  }; // End of file_stamp
//-----------------------------------------------------
//  Beginning of ROI: CTV
//-----------------------------------------------------

 roi={
           name: CTV
    volume_name: XXX^XXX
stats_volume_name: XXX^XXX
           author:   
           organ_name:   
           flags =          131072;
           roiinterpretedtype: ORGAN
           color:           lightblue
           box_size =       5;
           line_2d_width =  2;
           line_3d_width =  1;
           paint_brush_radius =  0.4;
           paint_allow_curve_closing = 1;
           curve_min_area =  0.01;
           curve_overlap_min =  88;
           lower =          800;
           upper =          4096;
           radius =         0;
           density =        1;
           density_units:   g/cm^3
           override_data =  0;
           override_order =  0;
           override_material =  0;
           material:        None
           invert_density_loading =  0;
           volume =         0;
           pixel_min =      0;
           pixel_max =      0;
           pixel_mean =     0;
           pixel_std =      0;
           bBEVDRROutline = 0;
           display_on_other_vols = 1;
           is_linked =      0;
           auto_update_contours =  0;
           UID: 2.16.840.1.113669.2.931128.555336727.20170210095226.736696
           stoppingpower =        0;
           ctnumber =        0;
           is_created_by_atlasseg = 0;
           is_created_by_autoplanengine = 0;
           num_curve = 17;
//----------------------------------------------------
//  ROI: CTV
//  Curve 1 of 17
//----------------------------------------------------
               curve={
                       flags =       131092;
                       block_size =  32;
                       num_points =  176;
points={
0.634699 15.4003 64.5
0.732355 15.4003 64.5
0.830011 15.4003 64.5
0.927668 15.4003 64.5
1.02532 15.4003 64.5
1.12298 15.4003 64.5
1.22063 15.4003 64.5
1.31829 15.4003 64.5
1.41595 15.4003 64.5
1.5136 15.4003 64.5
1.61126 15.4003 64.5
1.70892 15.3027 64.5
1.80657 15.3027 64.5
1.90423 15.3027 64.5
2.00188 15.3027 64.5
2.09954 15.3027 64.5
2.1972 15.205 64.5
2.29485 15.205 64.5
2.39251 15.1074 64.5
2.49016 15.0097 64.5
2.58782 15.0097 64.5
2.68547 14.9121 64.5
2.78313 14.8144 64.5
2.88079 14.7167 64.5
2.97844 14.6191 64.5
3.0761 14.5214 64.5
3.17376 14.4238 64.5
3.27141 14.3261 64.5
3.36907 14.2285 64.5
3.36907 14.1308 64.5
3.46672 14.0331 64.5
3.46672 13.9355 64.5
3.46672 13.8378 64.5
3.46672 13.7402 64.5
3.56438 13.6425 64.5
3.56438 13.5449 64.5
3.56438 13.4472 64.5
3.56438 13.3496 64.5
3.56438 13.2519 64.5
3.56438 13.1542 64.5
3.56438 13.0566 64.5
3.46672 12.9589 64.5
3.46672 12.8613 64.5
3.46672 12.7636 64.5
3.36907 12.666 64.5
3.36907 12.5683 64.5
3.27141 12.4707 64.5
3.17376 12.373 64.5
3.0761 12.2753 64.5
3.0761 12.1777 64.5
2.97844 12.08 64.5
2.97844 11.9824 64.5
2.88079 11.8847 64.5
2.88079 11.7871 64.5
2.88079 11.6894 64.5
2.78313 11.5917 64.5
2.78313 11.4941 64.5
2.68547 11.3964 64.5
2.68547 11.2988 64.5
2.58782 11.2011 64.5
2.68547 11.1035 64.5
2.68547 11.0058 64.5
2.68547 10.9082 64.5
2.78313 10.8105 64.5
2.78313 10.7128 64.5
2.88079 10.6152 64.5
2.88079 10.5175 64.5
2.97844 10.4199 64.5
2.97844 10.3222 64.5
2.97844 10.2246 64.5
2.88079 10.1269 64.5
2.88079 10.0293 64.5
2.78313 10.0293 64.5
2.68547 9.93159 64.5
2.58782 9.93159 64.5
2.49016 9.93159 64.5
2.39251 10.0293 64.5
2.29485 10.0293 64.5
2.1972 10.1269 64.5
2.09954 10.1269 64.5
2.00188 10.1269 64.5
1.90423 10.1269 64.5
1.80657 10.1269 64.5
1.70892 10.1269 64.5
1.61126 10.1269 64.5
1.5136 10.0293 64.5
1.41595 10.0293 64.5
1.31829 10.0293 64.5
1.22063 9.93159 64.5
1.12298 9.93159 64.5
1.02532 9.83394 64.5
0.927668 9.83394 64.5
0.830011 9.83394 64.5
0.732355 9.83394 64.5
0.634699 9.83394 64.5
0.537043 9.93159 64.5
0.439386 9.93159 64.5
0.341732 10.0293 64.5
0.244076 10.0293 64.5
0.14642 10.1269 64.5
0.0487633 10.1269 64.5
-0.048893 10.1269 64.5
-0.146549 10.2246 64.5
-0.244205 10.2246 64.5
-0.341862 10.2246 64.5
-0.439516 10.2246 64.5
-0.537172 10.2246 64.5
-0.634829 10.3222 64.5
-0.732485 10.3222 64.5
-0.830141 10.3222 64.5
-0.927797 10.3222 64.5
-1.02545 10.3222 64.5
-1.12311 10.3222 64.5
-1.22076 10.3222 64.5
-1.31842 10.3222 64.5
-1.41608 10.4199 64.5
-1.51373 10.4199 64.5
-1.51373 10.5175 64.5
-1.61139 10.6152 64.5
-1.61139 10.7128 64.5
-1.61139 10.8105 64.5
-1.61139 10.9082 64.5
-1.61139 11.0058 64.5
-1.61139 11.1035 64.5
-1.51373 11.2011 64.5
-1.51373 11.2988 64.5
-1.41608 11.3964 64.5
-1.31842 11.4941 64.5
-1.31842 11.5917 64.5
-1.22076 11.6894 64.5
-1.22076 11.7871 64.5
-1.22076 11.8847 64.5
-1.12311 11.9824 64.5
-1.12311 12.08 64.5
-1.12311 12.1777 64.5
-1.02545 12.2753 64.5
-1.02545 12.373 64.5
-1.02545 12.4707 64.5
-1.02545 12.5683 64.5
-1.02545 12.666 64.5
-1.02545 12.7636 64.5
-1.02545 12.8613 64.5
-1.02545 12.9589 64.5
-1.02545 13.0566 64.5
-1.02545 13.1542 64.5
-1.02545 13.2519 64.5
-1.02545 13.3496 64.5
-1.02545 13.4472 64.5
-1.02545 13.5449 64.5
-1.02545 13.6425 64.5
-1.02545 13.7402 64.5
-1.02545 13.8378 64.5
-1.02545 13.9355 64.5
-1.02545 14.0331 64.5
-1.02545 14.1308 64.5
-1.02545 14.2285 64.5
-1.02545 14.3261 64.5
-0.927797 14.4238 64.5
-0.927797 14.5214 64.5
-0.830141 14.6191 64.5
-0.830141 14.7167 64.5
-0.732485 14.8144 64.5
-0.634829 14.9121 64.5
-0.537172 14.9121 64.5
-0.439516 15.0097 64.5
-0.341862 15.0097 64.5
-0.244205 15.1074 64.5
-0.146549 15.1074 64.5
-0.048893 15.205 64.5
0.0487633 15.205 64.5
0.14642 15.3027 64.5
0.244076 15.3027 64.5
0.341732 15.3027 64.5
0.439386 15.3027 64.5
0.537043 15.3027 64.5
0.634699 15.4003 64.5
 };  // End of points for curve 1
}; // End of curve 1
//----------------------------------------------------
//  ROI: CTV
//  Curve 2 of 17
//----------------------------------------------------
               curve={
                       flags =       131092;
                       block_size =  32;
                       num_points =  159;
points={
0.634699 15.0097 63.5
0.732355 15.0097 63.5
0.830011 15.0097 63.5
0.927668 15.0097 63.5
1.02532 15.0097 63.5
1.12298 15.0097 63.5
1.22063 15.0097 63.5
1.31829 15.0097 63.5
1.41595 15.0097 63.5
1.5136 15.0097 63.5
1.61126 15.0097 63.5
1.70892 14.9121 63.5
1.80657 14.9121 63.5
1.90423 14.8144 63.5
2.00188 14.8144 63.5
2.09954 14.7167 63.5
2.1972 14.7167 63.5
2.29485 14.6191 63.5
2.39251 14.6191 63.5
2.49016 14.5214 63.5
2.58782 14.4238 63.5
2.68547 14.3261 63.5
2.68547 14.2285 63.5
2.78313 14.1308 63.5
2.88079 14.0331 63.5
2.88079 13.9355 63.5
2.97844 13.8378 63.5
2.97844 13.7402 63.5
2.97844 13.6425 63.5
3.0761 13.5449 63.5
3.0761 13.4472 63.5
3.0761 13.3496 63.5
3.0761 13.2519 63.5
3.0761 13.1542 63.5
3.0761 13.0566 63.5
3.0761 12.9589 63.5
3.0761 12.8613 63.5
3.0761 12.7636 63.5
3.0761 12.666 63.5
3.0761 12.5683 63.5
3.0761 12.4707 63.5
3.0761 12.373 63.5
3.0761 12.2753 63.5
3.0761 12.1777 63.5
2.97844 12.08 63.5
2.97844 11.9824 63.5
2.97844 11.8847 63.5
2.97844 11.7871 63.5
2.97844 11.6894 63.5
2.97844 11.5917 63.5
2.88079 11.4941 63.5
2.88079 11.3964 63.5
2.78313 11.2988 63.5
2.78313 11.2011 63.5
2.78313 11.1035 63.5
2.78313 11.0058 63.5
2.78313 10.9082 63.5
2.78313 10.8105 63.5
2.78313 10.7128 63.5
2.78313 10.6152 63.5
2.78313 10.5175 63.5
2.68547 10.4199 63.5
2.68547 10.3222 63.5
2.58782 10.2246 63.5
2.49016 10.2246 63.5
2.39251 10.1269 63.5
2.29485 10.1269 63.5
2.1972 10.0293 63.5
2.09954 10.0293 63.5
2.00188 9.93159 63.5
1.90423 9.83394 63.5
1.90423 9.73628 63.5
1.80657 9.73628 63.5
1.70892 9.63863 63.5
1.61126 9.63863 63.5
1.5136 9.54097 63.5
1.41595 9.44331 63.5
1.31829 9.34566 63.5
1.22063 9.248 63.5
1.22063 9.15035 63.5
1.12298 9.05269 63.5
1.02532 8.95504 63.5
0.927668 8.95504 63.5
0.830011 8.85738 63.5
0.732355 8.85738 63.5
0.634699 8.85738 63.5
0.537043 8.85738 63.5
0.439386 8.85738 63.5
0.341732 8.95504 63.5
0.244076 8.95504 63.5
0.244076 9.05269 63.5
0.14642 9.15035 63.5
0.14642 9.248 63.5
0.14642 9.34566 63.5
0.0487633 9.44331 63.5
-0.048893 9.54097 63.5
-0.048893 9.63863 63.5
-0.146549 9.73628 63.5
-0.244205 9.73628 63.5
-0.341862 9.83394 63.5
-0.439516 9.93159 63.5
-0.439516 10.0293 63.5
-0.537172 10.1269 63.5
-0.634829 10.1269 63.5
-0.732485 10.2246 63.5
-0.830141 10.3222 63.5
-0.927797 10.4199 63.5
-1.02545 10.5175 63.5
-1.12311 10.5175 63.5
-1.12311 10.6152 63.5
-1.22076 10.7128 63.5
-1.22076 10.8105 63.5
-1.31842 10.9082 63.5
-1.31842 11.0058 63.5
-1.31842 11.1035 63.5
-1.31842 11.2011 63.5
-1.31842 11.2988 63.5
-1.31842 11.3964 63.5
-1.22076 11.4941 63.5
-1.22076 11.5917 63.5
-1.22076 11.6894 63.5
-1.22076 11.7871 63.5
-1.22076 11.8847 63.5
-1.22076 11.9824 63.5
-1.22076 12.08 63.5
-1.22076 12.1777 63.5
-1.22076 12.2753 63.5
-1.22076 12.373 63.5
-1.12311 12.4707 63.5
-1.12311 12.5683 63.5
-1.02545 12.666 63.5
-1.02545 12.7636 63.5
-0.927797 12.8613 63.5
-0.927797 12.9589 63.5
-0.830141 13.0566 63.5
-0.830141 13.1542 63.5
-0.830141 13.2519 63.5
-0.830141 13.3496 63.5
-0.830141 13.4472 63.5
-0.732485 13.5449 63.5
-0.732485 13.6425 63.5
-0.634829 13.7402 63.5
-0.634829 13.8378 63.5
-0.537172 13.9355 63.5
-0.537172 14.0331 63.5
-0.439516 14.1308 63.5
-0.439516 14.2285 63.5
-0.341862 14.3261 63.5
-0.341862 14.4238 63.5
-0.244205 14.5214 63.5
-0.146549 14.6191 63.5
-0.048893 14.7167 63.5
0.0487633 14.7167 63.5
0.14642 14.8144 63.5
0.244076 14.8144 63.5
0.341732 14.9121 63.5
0.439386 14.9121 63.5
0.537043 14.9121 63.5
0.634699 15.0097 63.5
 };  // End of points for curve 2
}; // End of curve 2
//----------------------------------------------------
//  ROI: CTV
//  Curve 3 of 17
//----------------------------------------------------
               curve={
                       flags =       131092;
                       block_size =  32;
                       num_points =  250;
points={
-0.830141 15.8886 59.5
-0.732485 15.8886 59.5
-0.634829 15.8886 59.5
-0.537172 15.8886 59.5
-0.439516 15.791 59.5
-0.341862 15.791 59.5
-0.244205 15.6933 59.5
-0.146549 15.6933 59.5
-0.048893 15.5956 59.5
0.0487633 15.498 59.5
0.14642 15.4003 59.5
0.244076 15.4003 59.5
0.341732 15.4003 59.5
0.439386 15.4003 59.5
0.537043 15.4003 59.5
0.634699 15.4003 59.5
0.732355 15.4003 59.5
0.830011 15.498 59.5
0.927668 15.498 59.5
1.02532 15.498 59.5
1.12298 15.498 59.5
1.22063 15.5956 59.5
1.31829 15.5956 59.5
1.41595 15.5956 59.5
1.5136 15.5956 59.5
1.61126 15.5956 59.5
1.70892 15.5956 59.5
1.80657 15.5956 59.5
1.90423 15.5956 59.5
2.00188 15.5956 59.5
2.09954 15.5956 59.5
2.1972 15.5956 59.5
2.29485 15.5956 59.5
2.39251 15.498 59.5
2.49016 15.498 59.5
2.58782 15.498 59.5
2.68547 15.498 59.5
2.78313 15.4003 59.5
2.88079 15.4003 59.5
2.97844 15.3027 59.5
3.0761 15.205 59.5
3.17376 15.1074 59.5
3.27141 15.0097 59.5
3.36907 14.9121 59.5
3.36907 14.8144 59.5
3.46672 14.7167 59.5
3.56438 14.6191 59.5
3.66203 14.5214 59.5
3.75969 14.4238 59.5
3.85735 14.3261 59.5
3.85735 14.2285 59.5
3.955 14.1308 59.5
3.955 14.0331 59.5
4.05266 13.9355 59.5
4.05266 13.8378 59.5
4.15031 13.7402 59.5
4.15031 13.6425 59.5
4.15031 13.5449 59.5
4.15031 13.4472 59.5
4.24797 13.3496 59.5
4.24797 13.2519 59.5
4.24797 13.1542 59.5
4.24797 13.0566 59.5
4.24797 12.9589 59.5
4.24797 12.8613 59.5
4.34563 12.7636 59.5
4.34563 12.666 59.5
4.34563 12.5683 59.5
4.34563 12.4707 59.5
4.44328 12.373 59.5
4.44328 12.2753 59.5
4.44328 12.1777 59.5
4.44328 12.08 59.5
4.44328 11.9824 59.5
4.44328 11.8847 59.5
4.44328 11.7871 59.5
4.44328 11.6894 59.5
4.44328 11.5917 59.5
4.44328 11.4941 59.5
4.44328 11.3964 59.5
4.44328 11.2988 59.5
4.44328 11.2011 59.5
4.34563 11.1035 59.5
4.34563 11.0058 59.5
4.34563 10.9082 59.5
4.24797 10.8105 59.5
4.24797 10.7128 59.5
4.15031 10.6152 59.5
4.05266 10.5175 59.5
4.05266 10.4199 59.5
4.05266 10.3222 59.5
4.05266 10.2246 59.5
3.955 10.1269 59.5
3.955 10.0293 59.5
3.955 9.93159 59.5
3.85735 9.83394 59.5
3.85735 9.73628 59.5
3.75969 9.63863 59.5
3.66203 9.54097 59.5
3.66203 9.44331 59.5
3.66203 9.34566 59.5
3.56438 9.248 59.5
3.56438 9.15035 59.5
3.46672 9.05269 59.5
3.36907 8.95504 59.5
3.36907 8.85738 59.5
3.27141 8.85738 59.5
3.17376 8.75972 59.5
3.0761 8.66207 59.5
2.97844 8.66207 59.5
2.88079 8.56441 59.5
2.78313 8.56441 59.5
2.68547 8.56441 59.5
2.58782 8.56441 59.5
2.49016 8.56441 59.5
2.39251 8.66207 59.5
2.29485 8.66207 59.5
2.1972 8.75972 59.5
2.09954 8.75972 59.5
2.09954 8.85738 59.5
2.00188 8.95504 59.5
1.90423 9.05269 59.5
1.80657 9.05269 59.5
1.70892 9.15035 59.5
1.61126 9.15035 59.5
1.5136 9.248 59.5
1.41595 9.248 59.5
1.31829 9.15035 59.5
1.22063 9.15035 59.5
1.12298 9.15035 59.5
1.02532 9.15035 59.5
0.927668 9.15035 59.5
0.830011 9.15035 59.5
0.732355 9.05269 59.5
0.634699 9.05269 59.5
0.537043 8.95504 59.5
0.537043 8.85738 59.5
0.537043 8.75972 59.5
0.439386 8.66207 59.5
0.439386 8.56441 59.5
0.341732 8.46675 59.5
0.244076 8.46675 59.5
0.14642 8.3691 59.5
0.0487633 8.3691 59.5
-0.048893 8.3691 59.5
-0.146549 8.46675 59.5
-0.244205 8.46675 59.5
-0.244205 8.56441 59.5
-0.341862 8.66207 59.5
-0.341862 8.75972 59.5
-0.341862 8.85738 59.5
-0.439516 8.95504 59.5
-0.439516 9.05269 59.5
-0.537172 9.15035 59.5
-0.634829 9.248 59.5
-0.732485 9.248 59.5
-0.830141 9.34566 59.5
-0.927797 9.34566 59.5
-1.02545 9.34566 59.5
-1.12311 9.34566 59.5
-1.22076 9.34566 59.5
-1.31842 9.248 59.5
-1.41608 9.248 59.5
-1.51373 9.15035 59.5
-1.61139 9.15035 59.5
-1.70905 9.05269 59.5
-1.8067 9.05269 59.5
-1.90436 9.05269 59.5
-2.00201 8.95504 59.5
-2.09967 8.95504 59.5
-2.19732 8.95504 59.5
-2.29498 8.95504 59.5
-2.39264 8.95504 59.5
-2.49029 8.95504 59.5
-2.58795 9.05269 59.5
-2.6856 9.05269 59.5
-2.78326 9.15035 59.5
-2.88092 9.248 59.5
-2.88092 9.34566 59.5
-2.97857 9.44331 59.5
-2.97857 9.54097 59.5
-2.97857 9.63863 59.5
-2.97857 9.73628 59.5
-2.97857 9.83394 59.5
-2.97857 9.93159 59.5
-2.97857 10.0293 59.5
-2.88092 10.1269 59.5
-2.88092 10.2246 59.5
-2.78326 10.3222 59.5
-2.78326 10.4199 59.5
-2.6856 10.5175 59.5
-2.6856 10.6152 59.5
-2.58795 10.7128 59.5
-2.58795 10.8105 59.5
-2.49029 10.9082 59.5
-2.39264 11.0058 59.5
-2.29498 11.1035 59.5
-2.29498 11.2011 59.5
-2.29498 11.2988 59.5
-2.29498 11.3964 59.5
-2.29498 11.4941 59.5
-2.29498 11.5917 59.5
-2.29498 11.6894 59.5
-2.29498 11.7871 59.5
-2.39264 11.8847 59.5
-2.49029 11.9824 59.5
-2.49029 12.08 59.5
-2.58795 12.1777 59.5
-2.58795 12.2753 59.5
-2.58795 12.373 59.5
-2.58795 12.4707 59.5
-2.58795 12.5683 59.5
-2.58795 12.666 59.5
-2.58795 12.7636 59.5
-2.58795 12.8613 59.5
-2.58795 12.9589 59.5
-2.58795 13.0566 59.5
-2.58795 13.1542 59.5
-2.49029 13.2519 59.5
-2.49029 13.3496 59.5
-2.39264 13.4472 59.5
-2.39264 13.5449 59.5
-2.39264 13.6425 59.5
-2.39264 13.7402 59.5
-2.39264 13.8378 59.5
-2.29498 13.9355 59.5
-2.29498 14.0331 59.5
-2.29498 14.1308 59.5
-2.19732 14.2285 59.5
-2.19732 14.3261 59.5
-2.09967 14.4238 59.5
-2.09967 14.5214 59.5
-2.09967 14.6191 59.5
-2.00201 14.7167 59.5
-2.00201 14.8144 59.5
-1.90436 14.9121 59.5
-1.90436 15.0097 59.5
-1.8067 15.1074 59.5
-1.8067 15.205 59.5
-1.70905 15.205 59.5
-1.61139 15.3027 59.5
-1.61139 15.4003 59.5
-1.51373 15.498 59.5
-1.41608 15.5956 59.5
-1.31842 15.6933 59.5
-1.22076 15.6933 59.5
-1.12311 15.791 59.5
-1.02545 15.791 59.5
-0.927797 15.791 59.5
-0.830141 15.8886 59.5
 };  // End of points for curve 3
}; // End of curve 3
//----------------------------------------------------
//  ROI: PTV
//  Curve 1 of 17
//----------------------------------------------------
               curve={
                       flags =       131092;
                       block_size =  32;
                       num_points =  166;
```

My goal is to extract only the numerical data after the `"// ROI: CTV"` and before `"// ROI: PTV"`. My second goal is to manipulate this data where the third column = 64.5.

Comment: Which *numerical data* specifically ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to reduce the volume of data, but still keep the points of interest?

Comment: in case my answer is fine, could you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: The data i'd like to extract are curves, part of a Region of Interest. These curves consist of a series of three points: (x,y,z). I'm interested to extract only a curve with a well defined z value and then shift all x-values of a certain amount.

Comment: Ok, the code I wrote below just extracts all numerical values, since you did not specify exactly what should be extracted. Just change it a bit and ensure that when you get a line it should have 3 elements (x,y,z) and ignore the others. You can also define a better structure than a `data[]` to store the results.

Comment: My final intent is to extract only one of the many curves, eg Curve 2 of 17, maybe in a shape more similar to an array, editing only the first column. Like this:

points={
0.634699 15.0097 63.5
0.732355 15.0097 63.5
0.830011 15.0097 63.5
etc. etc. etc.}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this should work,
but you can improve the code!

```
import re
data = []
in_file = False
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as infile:
     for line in infile:
          if "ROI: CTV" in line: in_file = True
          if "ROI: PTV" in line: in_file = False
          if in_file:
              line = line.split(' ')
              for item in line:
                  if re.search(r'(?<![a-zA-Z:])[-+]?\d*\.?\d+', item):
                      match = re.search(r'(?<![a-zA-Z:])[-+]?\d*\.?\d+', item)
                      data.append(match.group(0))


print data
```

Comment: Thanks, today is a national holiday in Italy, tomorrow I try and tell you how it went.

Comment: It doesn't work. The stopping point is exceeded and ends at the end of the text.

Comment: what do you mean? the code above might grab more data than you need, since it takes any int/float but should stop at soon the `ROI: PTV` string is found. Please elaborate a bit more what you need with an example or what is the actual issue.

Comment: Dear Alg_D, I'm new on Python programming and I apologize for this, but if i try the code you wrote i find in "data" points from ROI: CTV and ROI: PTV. Why do not you try yourself? the loop doesn't stop where we would.

Comment: Dear Alg_D, I'm new on Python programming and I beg your pardon for this, but if i try the code you wrote i find in "data" points from ROI: CTV and points from ROI: PTV. Why do not you try yourself? the loop doesn't stop.
I explain again what I'd like to do: I have a text file containing a lot of Rois, //ROI: CTV, //ROI: PTV and many others. My goal is to select a well defined curve of a well defined ROI and add a fixed value to all x points. I do not want to bore you on why use Python and not Matlab (easier choice!!!) but I can only work with this.
That'all folks. 
Thanks for your time

Comment: ha yes, the check to exit was in the wrong place. Anyway, note that this will take ANY number, including this '3' in the line:  `End of points for curve 3`. You might need to filter this out. Perhaps by using regular expressions. I edited my Answer

Comment: With the addition of a "break" works. I had noticed there were unwanted numeric values. Those I need are those that are not preceded by anything but braces "{};", some hints? Thanks.

Comment: I can't test it now, but I guess you can use another approach. Like take/add to `datap[]` all values in one line just in case the whole line contains numeric values. so we add 3 values in this case `0.634699 15.4003 64.5` but none on this case `num_points =  176;`  You need first to check that all `item in line`: are numeric and if so add them to `data`

Comment: By the right regular expression I'm able to filter out Unwanted values.
The following line: re.search(r'[-+]?(?:\d*\.\d+)',item).