# Extracting and editing a part of a paragraph of a text

Tags: python

I have the following problem that was only partially solved in a previous post: I have a particular type of text file, this file contains the information of a series of Roi of a patient for a Radiotherapy treatment, I would like to identify a portion of text that contains a series of numbers (objective achieved in the previous post) editing a part of these numbers and save them in the original file.
I enclose a copy of the Roi file:

```
    code starts here

// Region of Interest file
// Data set:
// File created: Mon Sep  4 17:17:19 2017

//
// Pinnacle Treatment Planning System Version 9.10 
// 9.10 
//

 file_stamp={
       write_date: Mon Sep  4 17:17:19 2017
    write_program: Pinnacle Treatment Planning System
    write_version: 9.10
  }; // End of file_stamp
//-----------------------------------------------------
//  Beginning of ROI: Couch
//-----------------------------------------------------

 roi={
           name: Couch
    volume_name:
stats_volume_name: 
           author:   
           organ_name:   
           flags =          16;
           roiinterpretedtype: ORGAN
           color:           skyblue
           box_size =       5;
           line_2d_width =  2;
           line_3d_width =  1;
           paint_brush_radius =  0.4;
           paint_allow_curve_closing = 1;
           curve_min_area =  0.1;
           curve_overlap_min =  88;
           lower =          800;
           upper =          4096;
           radius =         0;
           density =        1;
           density_units:   g/cm^3
           override_data =  0;
           override_order =  0;
           override_material =  0;
           material:        None
           invert_density_loading =  0;
           volume =         0;
           pixel_min =      0;
           pixel_max =      0;
           pixel_mean =     0;
           pixel_std =      0;
           bBEVDRROutline = 0;
           display_on_other_vols = 1;
           is_linked =      0;
           auto_update_contours =  0;
           UID: 2.16.840.1.113669.2.931128.555336727.20170904171440.8062
           stoppingpower =        0;
           ctnumber =        0;
           is_created_by_atlasseg = 0;
           is_created_by_autoplanengine = 0;
           num_curve = 2;
//----------------------------------------------------
//  ROI: Couch
//  Curve 1 of 2
//----------------------------------------------------
               curve={
                       flags =       20;
                       block_size =  32;
                       num_points =  6;
points={
-23.5328 6.25885 40
23.7286 6.25885 40
23.8268 2.14121 40
-23.5328 2.04318 40
-23.5328 6.25885 40
-23.5328 6.25885 40
 };  // End of points for curve 1
}; // End of curve 1
//----------------------------------------------------
//  ROI: Couch
//  Curve 2 of 2
//----------------------------------------------------
               curve={
                       flags =       20;
                       block_size =  32;
                       num_points =  6;
points={
-23.5328 5.52735 65
23.7286 5.52735 65
23.8268 2.14121 65
-23.5328 2.04318 65
-23.5328 5.52735 65
-23.5328 5.52735 65
 };  // End of points for curve 2
}; // End of curve 2
               surface_mesh={
                       allow_adaptation = 1;
                       replace_mean_mesh = 0;
                       auto_clean_contours = 1;
                       auto_smooth_mesh = 1;
                       internal_weight = -3.000000;
                       surface_weight = 1.000000;
                       distance_weight = 2.000000;
                       profile_length = 10;
                       limit_feature_search_string: Full
                       pixel_size = 1.000000;
                       feature_weight = 0.010000;
                       lower_CT_bound = 0.000000;
                       upper_CT_bound = 4095.000000;
                       gradient_clipping: Soft
                       gradient_direction: Unsigned
                       maximum_gradient = 100.000000;
                       avoid_CT_range: None
                       avoid_CT_threshold = 4095.000000;
                       number_of_modes = 0;
                       number_of_vertices = 0;
                       number_of_triangles = 0;
                       max_iterations = 10;
                       smooth_between_iterations = 0;
                       repair_between_iterations = 1;
                       translation_increment_cm = 0.500000;
                       rotation_increment = 20.000000;
                       magnify_increment = 0.200000;
                       sphere_tool_radius = 1.500000;
                       gaussian_tool_radius = 3.000000;
                       vertex_drag_curvature = 0.700000;
                       vertex_drag_neighbor_layers = 3;
                       vertices={
 };  // End of vertices for surface mesh
                       triangles={
 };  // End of triangles for surface mesh
}; // End of surface_mesh 
               mean_mesh={
                       samples = 0;
                       number_of_vertices = 0;
                       number_of_triangles = 0;
                       vertices={
 };  // End of vertices for mean mesh
                       triangles={
 };  // End of triangles for mean mesh
}; // End of mean_mesh 
        }; // End of ROI Couch


   code ends here
```

I am interested in extracting only the numerical values (x, y, z) in the part of the paragraph defined by Roi: Couch for all its curves. With the regular expression I was able to extract these values but also unwanted values such as:

```
//  Curve 1 of 2
//----------------------------------------------------
               curve={
                       flags =       20;
                       block_size =  32;
                       num_points =  6;
points={
```

These values are added to those desired: 1 2 20 32 6 (unwanted) -23.5328 6.25885 40 etc. etc. (desired).
These values are added to the desired values: 1 2 20 32 6 (unwanted) -23.5328 6.25885 40 etc. etc. (desired).
The last step is to vary the x and y of a known value --> -123.5328 106.25885 and enter these new values instead of the original values in the original file.
In this way I have the displacement in x, y of my Roi in the Cartesian plane.
Thank you for all the help you can give me.

Comment: a link to the previous post might be useful

Comment: Sorry, You're right.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591478/python-find-a-portion-of-a-text-file-to-export-as-data-to-manipulate/43592141?noredirect=1#comment74370382_43592141